# New bundled expo-cli start is returning a manifest that cannot be parsed by expo-dev-launcher

Tags: expo, eas

We are currently going through the upgrade to expo SDK 47, following these instructions:
https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-47-a0f6f5c038af

Part of the upgrade involves the recommended switch to using the bundled expo-cli, rather than the global instance.

When we make this change, and run `npx expo start --dev-client`, our android app throws an error when selecting the dev server, with the message:

`Value ----------------------------224819657222108214122421 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

When I hit the dev server url (eg. http://192.168.0.146:8081/?platform=android) manually to obtain the manifest, I can see it is indeed starting with the above value, as it contains some meta-data, eg.

```
----------------------------224819657222108214122421
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="manifest"
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":"f5c3b7be-999c-436e-b9c4-b453cf873af0","createdAt":"2023-01-12T10:13:41.499Z","runtimeVersion":"1.e","launchAsset":{"key":"bundle","contentType":"application/javascript","url":"http://10.20.0.174:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false"},"asset
...
```

When I switch back to using the globally installed CLI as per the instructions in the upgrade blog, so changing the start command from `npx expo start` to `expo-cli start`, the same test results in the manifest being returned without the supplementary data, and the app can be loaded successfully.

Comment: Also hitting this error (expo 47, eas-cli 3.8.1) and am unable to find a solution. App runs when built via expo run:android but hits this exact error when running the dev client generated via eas build --android --local